# Unable to download Spring Tool Suite(STS) in eclipse mars.2

Tags: spring-tool-suite, eclipse-mars

I am trying to install the Spring Tool Suite(STS) in my eclipse mars.2 via eclipse market place (eclipse->Help[tab]->Eclipse market place). When I search for STS in the search bar 0 result is returning.

Can anyone help me why this is happening?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzpsU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest version of STS3 that was compatible with Eclipse Mars (4.5) from here:

http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.5

*(please note, this is an p2 repository URL, which is meant to be used in the Eclipse "Install New Software" dialog, there is no index page being served under this URL that can be accessed by a browser).*

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin. Anyway instead of installing STS in eclipse mars2, I have installed the file from the website www.eclipse.org. I got a zip file. After unzipping, i got a STS.exe file.

Comment: The official download page for the ready-to-use Spring Tool Suite version 3 can be found here, in case you really need an old version: https://spring.io/tools3/sts/legacy - but I would highly recommend to use the latest version, which is STS 3.9.7 at the moment, based on Eclipse 2018-12 - or even try Spring Tools 4 from here: https://spring.io/tools/ - which is focused on Spring Boot and comes with a different set of features - choose whatever fits your needs

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thanks for helping me again Martin